# making a single sas table with three groups instead of multiple tables

Tags: sas

I need help making a table that meets the conditions of a hw problem I have...I don't need the answer, rather help getting to what I need!

The question goes as follows:
Report the means and standard deviations of the newborn weights for these three groups in a single SAS table

here are the code I have:

```
data newset;
set mysubset;
bbywt = 99;
if dbwt < 9999  then bbywt = .0022046*(dbwt);

    format meansdata $50.;
    meansdata = 'na';
    if  RF_GDIAB = 'Y' AND RF_PHYPE = 'N' then meansdata = 'Case 1';
    if  RF_GDIAB = 'Y' AND RF_PHYPE = 'Y' then meansdata ='Case 2';
    if  RF_GDIAB = 'N' AND RF_PHYPE = 'N'
AND RF_PDIAB = 'N' AND  RF_GHYPE = 'N'  then meansdata ='Case 3';
run;

PROC univariate DATA = newset;
title 'Assignment 4 Q1 means table';
ods select basicmeasures;
var bbywt;
class meansdata;
where meansdata ~= 'na' and bbywt <99; 
run;
```

whenever I run it I get three tables and I want it in one table with three rows... should I use `proc corr` or I just need to set it up differently? I need the var to be the converted weight of the baby `bbywt`, was it right to have the `meansdata` set up as the class statement?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Since you want to calculate the MEANS why not use PROC MEANS?

Comment: By "table" do you mean a report or a dataset?  Your code appears to only be creating a report, not any datasets.

Comment: that was my bad with creating a new data set, let me edit out the first half of the code.

Comment: by table I mean report, as in the results returning a report of the ods select basic statistical measures. It returns three separate reports for class 1, class 2, class 3

Comment: Wow, the PROC MEANS table got the job done, thank you. It was way more simple than I thought